Bluetooth to WiFi/Cell Gateway?
first and foremost, my experience has shown that knowing the proper names for technologies and ideas is a huge leg up. With that in mind, I don't really know what this idea would be called so please pardon me if this is silly and already exists and I simply do not know the keywords or how to find the solution.
The Problem:
I have an overlanding rig (Car Camping + Off-roading), which has a lot of Bluetooth enabled devices (a fridge, my power system for managing solar input and accessory current draw etc). I'd like to be able to monitor these stats from afar. Even while my truck is parked at home, I'd like to be able to monitor its "vitals".
The Solution?:
An idea I had was to use a Raspberry Pi to somehow create a bridge/proxy for the BT devices? That is to say, they would connect to the Pi via BT, and then it would allow my phone to "remote in?" to the Pi or something?
I don't know if there is a more "official" way to somehow proxy the BT data to the phone in a way that it "trusts" that the information is coming in over a BT connection and everything "just works".
Thoughts?

You've asked an interesting question. However, I’m voting to close it because it does not follow our "rules". You might consider posting it on Hardware Recommendations, or Internet of Things... that might be a better fit. You can look over the list of SE sites by clicking the "hamburger patty" icon in the URHC of this page. If you get your question sorted out, and the solution does involve Raspberry Pi, please don't hesitate to ask a proper question here.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
